# Nginx Configuration for GET request with Body not working

Tags: nginx, aws-api-gateway, nginx-reverse-proxy, nginx-config, nginx-location

I have a GET endpoint configured in AWS API gateway. When I trigger the endpoint directly it's working fine. Below is the endpoint which is a GET request with a json body,

```
curl -X GET \
  -d '{"pageSize":"10", "pageNumber":"1", "id": "xyz"}' \
  "https://abcd.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/xyz/audit/list"
```

This request returns a 200 response. But when I try to invoke it using an endpoint configured in nginx it returns the error as,

```
<html>

<head>
    <title>
        ERROR accessing content
    </title>
</head>

<body>
    <h1 color='red'>HTTP Error 4xx: Content is not available</h1>
</body>

</html>
```

Looks like my nginx configuration is having issues to identify a GET request with body.

The nginx configuration is as below,

```
server {
    listen 443 ssl proxy_protocol;

    location /xyz/audit/list {
            proxy_pass https://abcd.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/xyz/audit/list;
            proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-For  $proxy_protocol_addr;
            proxy_pass_request_headers on;
            proxy_method GET;
            add_header X-Body $request_body;
            add_header X-Frame-Options DENY;
            add_header 'Cache-Control' 'no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate, proxy-revalidate, max-age=0';
            add_header 'Pragma' 'no-cache';
            add_header X-Content-Type-Options nosniff;
            add_header X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block";
            add_header Content-Security-Policy "frame-ancestors 'self'";
            add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains" always;
            expires off;
    }

}
```

When I invoke a GET request with body for above configuration it fails. What am I missing here? Do I need to add any more parameters in nginx configuration. Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Note: Same configuration as above works if I invoke the POST request with json body.

Comment: Things randomly dropping bodies from GET request is expected. Don't rely on this behavior. HTTP servers and proxies that do that are no incorrect per the HTTP spec. If this is your API, I would suggest you change it to not use GET request bodies.

Comment: Instead of adding stuff in the config I suggest removing and reproduce with a simpler setup: simple proxy, no ssl and see it work in this simple setup first. A working example of a simple setup can be found here: https://github.com/ericminio/learning-nginx/tree/master/proxy_get_body.